# Custom slider component Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

Im working on creating a custom slider component in lightning. I don't want to use the one provided as it has quite limited functionality.

I'm seeing the slider on the page, but get the error:

[knob.addEventListener is not a function]

Component:

```
<!-- Should be auto-set -->
<aura:attribute name="Height" type="Integer"/>
<aura:attribute name="Width" type="Integer"/>

<aura:attribute name="Steps" type="Integer[]" default="[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]"/>
<aura:attribute name="stepChange" type="Integer" default="1"/>
<aura:attribute name="Tick" type="Integer" default="0.1"/>

<aura:attribute name="Orientation" type="String" default="Horizontal"/> 

<aura:attribute name="Min" type="Integer" default="0"/>
<aura:attribute name="Max" type="Integer" default="100"/>
<aura:attribute name="Value" type="Integer" default="10"/>

<!-- Handlers  -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<div id='track' aura:id="track" class="track">
<div id="knob" aura:id="knob" onmousedown="{!c.onMouseDown}" class="knob"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
   .THIS .track 
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 5px;
    margin:100px; 
    background: red
}
.THIS .knob 
{
    height: 10px; 
    width: 40px; 
    background: black;
    position: relative; 
}
```

helper.js

```
({
    initialLoad: function(component, event, helper) {

        var dragging = false;
        var knobOffset = 0;

        var track = component.find("track"),
            knob = component.find("knob"),

            trackWidth = track.offsetWidth,
            trackLeft = track.offsetLeft,
            trackRight = trackLeft + trackWidth,

            knobWidth = knob.offsetWidth,
            maxRight = trackWidth - knobWidth; // relatively to track

        window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
            dragging = false;
        })

        window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
            if (dragging) {
                // current knob offset, relative to track
                var offset = e.clientX - trackLeft - knobOffset;
                if (offset < 0) {
                    var offset = 0;
                } else if (offset > maxRight) {
                    var offset = maxRight;
                }

                knob.style.left = offset + "px"
            }
        });
    },

    onMouseDown: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(here);
        var knob = component.find("knob");

        knob.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
            // knob offset relatively to track
            knobOffset = e.clientX - knob.offsetLeft;
            dragging = true;
        });
    },
})
```

controller.js

```
 ({
        doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
            helper.initialLoad(component, event, helper);
        },
        onMouseDown: function(component,event,helper) {
    console.log("mousedown");
    helper.onMouseDown(component,event,helper);
},
    })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some parts are missing. To help us understanding it, please add your whole component and your `onRender` method.

Comment: @Basti Updated, i've removed the OnRender as it was a different approach i've since deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be it a custom component or an HTML element when you do [component.find()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_find_by_id.htm) we get an intended target's component instance rather than the actual DOM.

In order to access the DOM, you need this:

> component.find().getElement(); // return the DOM of a component instance

So your `onMouseDown` method would look like this:

```
onMouseDown: function(component, event, helper) {
     var knob = component.find("knob").getElement();

     knob.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
         // knob offset relatively to track
         knobOffset = e.clientX - knob.offsetLeft;
    });
},
```

Comment: Thanks, that removes the error, however theres still no movement from the slider, any idea as to why?

Answer (score 1):

To apply the CSS to your elements you would need to define it like this:

```
.THIS.track 
{...}
.THIS.knob 
{...}
```

The divs are in the first level of your components, and `.THIS` (the class name of your Component) is applied to first level elements in your component. In the DOM it will look like this:

```
<div id="track" class="YourComponent">
```

Therefore you need to chain the selectors without spaces. `.THIS .foo` only applies to `foo` elements within the `.THIS` component.

Not sure if this fixes your viability issues, but it at least let's you apply your css to your elements.

BTW:

```
<div id="knob" aura:id="knob" mousedown="{!c.onMouseDown}" class="knob"></div>
```

should be:

```
<div id="knob" aura:id="knob" onmousedown="{!c.onMouseDown}" class="knob"></div>
```

Comment: For some reason only track shows with the CSS like that, the Knob is being treated as a class. However, its now showing at least. No movement on the slider, the mousedown isn't being recognised.

Comment: I just saw you edited your question and added the classes, I will quickly update my answer.

Comment: So it is displaying, but you're having problems with your mthods?
 maybe you should clarify this in your question. `console.log(here);` would be undefined btw.. You are using the wrong event: `mousedown` should be `onmousedown`

Comment: Thanks i didn't spot that! the error im getting is " [knob.addEventListener is not a function]", i will update the question.

Comment: just a quick note, try to avoid updating your question everytime there are new developments/errors in your code, insread, please open a new post with the new issue you are facing. Thanks!